# Ionic 5 Capacitor - How to change the status bar background color dynamically on IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5

I'm using Capacitor with Ionic 5 and I need to change the status bar background color dynamically (different colors on different pages). On Android everything works fine (both capacitor and cordova plugins work), but on IOS I found out some limitations:

1. `cordova-plugin-statusbar` is [not compatible with Capacitor for IOS](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins)
2. From Capacitor status bar plugin, the method `setBackgroundColor` is [not supported for IOS](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar)

Is there any workaround to achieve my goal on IOS?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a solution. Status bar on IOS is transparent, so there is an easy solution to just set the background color on the body of the app, for example: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#e34233";`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using "cordova-plugin-statusbar" varsion 2.4.2

I have solved this issue by this:

```
  this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3300000000');
```

You can dynamically set your status bar color

Comment: cordova-plugin-statusbar is not supported by IOS with Capacitor